# Check if workflows are used or not?

Tags: sharepoint

We are migrating content from one SharePoint (MOSS 2007) to new platform (SP 2013). We have situation where we have to fix some items manually on each site.

Is there a way I can know if any workflow is used in the site or not?

P.S: Workflow related features are enabled on all the sites. We can see the workflows in list settings ofcourse but I want to check on site level if workflow is used anywhere on the site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

List workflows are run against items in that list. So my thoughts would be no. My recommendation would be open SPD and check the workflows there. If they're list workflows then they run against that list and to my knowledge that list exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is that you need to custom code it in Visual Studio and log the sites with workflows, steps

1. Open Site
2. Iterate through the lists in the site
3. `if(sPList.WorkflowAssociations.Count > 0 )` the site contains workflow somewhere in some list